# Remove all debuggers that ARE NOT between single or double quotes

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds

I am trying to implement a regex expression that removes all debuggers from a file unless that debugger is within...

1. Single quotes
2. Double quotes

I have the below code which works for double quotes but I'm not sure how to include single quotes as well.

```js
var removeDebuggers = (str) => {

  str = str.replace(/debugger(?=([^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)/g, "");

  console.log(str)

}

removeDebuggers(`
  Here is a 'debugger' in single quotes. 
  - DOESN'T WORK.
  Another "debugger test" but with double quotes.
  - WORKS.
  "Testing this debugger also." 
  - WORKS.
  My final debugger not in quotes. 
  - WORKS.
  `)
```

The outcome I am working toward is where the debugger in "`Here is a 'debugger' in single quotes.`" also does not get removed. Any `debugger` that IS NOT within double or single quotes should be left alone.

Comment: Not an answer, but why `debugger+`? This will remove `debuggerrrrrrr` which isn't what you want, I think. Also, "Any `debugger` that IS NOT within double or single quotes should be left alone." should read "...should be removed." right? You want to leave alone the ones that *are* in quotes.

Comment: This is not a task for regex. At least, not this way.

Comment: @apsillers thank you for pointing those out. The `+` was in their from a previous attempt and was left in by mistake. I also edited the last line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you remove a string in all contexts but inside single or double quotes, it is easier to match the quotes and capture them in a group to restore in the resulting string later with a backreference to that group in the replacement pattern:

```
str = str.replace(/("[^"]*"|'[^']*')|debugger/g, "$1");
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tcWpge/1).

**Details**

- `("[^"]*"|'[^']*')` - Group 1 (referred to with `$1` from the replacement pattern):

  - `"[^"]*"` - `"`, 0 or more chars other than `"` and then a `"`
  - `|` - or
  - `'[^']*'` - `'`, 0 or more chars other than `'` and then a `'`
- `|` - or
- `debugger` - a substring.

To match `debugger` as a whole word, use word boundaries, `\bdebugger\b`.

To support escape sequences inside single/double quotes extend `("[^"]*"|'[^']*')` pattern as `("[^"\\]*(?:\\[\s\S][^"\\]*)*"|'[^'\\]*(?:\\[\s\S][^'\\]*)*')`. Or, better, `((?:^|[^\/])(?:\\{2})*"[^"\\]*(?:\\[\s\S][^"\\]*)*"|'[^'\\]*(?:\\[\s\S][^'\\]*)*')`.

So, the enhanced version would look like

```
str = str.replace(/((?:^|[^\/])(?:\\{2})*"[^"\\]*(?:\\[\s\S][^"\\]*)*"|'[^'\\]*(?:\\[\s\S][^'\\]*)*')|\bdebugger\b/g, '$1');
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tcWpge/2).

Comment: About the last pattern: `[^\/]` is probably `[^\\]`, and not sure that looking for *"escaped"* quotes outside quoted substrings does make sense.